# How to increase the size of just one word or letter in a text without affect the line above?

Tags: css, wordpress, text, line

I am designing a Wordpress website.
In this case I try to change the color AND the size of just the point in the end of the headline. Now the height of the point pushes the line above .

Question: How to increase the size of just one word or letter in a text without affect the line above?

Below is the image of issue.
[image: Image of the Issue]

Comment: Please post your code as code snipped with included CSS so we can reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think it can help you.

```css
div {
    font-size: 24px;
    text-align: center;
}
span {
    font-size: 30px;
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<div>This is sample <span>text</span></div>
```

Comment: So do you want to change style of "NEN."?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I have forgot to say I add alreadey some CSS code.

```
<h1 class="title"><span class="lead solid-color">
Wir helfen Unternehmen dabei ihre Mitarbeitergewinnung zu digitalisieren und mehr qualifizierte Fachkräfte zu gewinnen</span> <span>.</span>
</h1>

.title span:nth-child(2)
{
    font-size: 72pt!important;
    font-family: 'Roboto Slab',   serif!important;
}
```